# Passing Data from Parent Window of One domain to Child window of another domian

Tags: javascript, html, webforms, parent-child

I have two domains say X and Y, both are on different server with different IPs.

Now the case is that on one page of domain X there is a Link which opens the pop-up of domain Y.

User searches for some data on that popup and then clicks on "Done"

On click the values related to the searched field should be passed to a page on domain X.

I am using PHP, HTML, and js for this.

P.S.:  The thing works when the domain name is same but I want the solution where domain names and server are different.

Comment: Check out this JSONP example: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/

Answer (score 7):

I just want to add that it is *possible* to pass data from a window with one domain to a window with another domain via the `window.name` property. Of course, this property wasn't intended for that purpose, and **language purists are going to hate me for this**. Nonetheless, this is how it's done, quick and dirty:

On Domain X:

```
var PREFIX = "your prefix here";
// The second parameter of window.open() sets window.name of the child window.
// Encode JSON and prepend prefix.
window.open("http://domain-y.example.com/", PREFIX + JSON.stringify({"foo":"bar", "abc":123}));
```

On Domain Y:

```
var PREFIX = "your prefix here";
if(window.name.substr(0, PREFIX.length) == PREFIX){
    // Remove prefix and decode JSON
    var data = JSON.parse(window.name.substring(PREFIX.length));
    // Do what you need to do with the data here.
    alert(data.foo); // Should alert "bar"
}
```

The `PREFIX` is optional, but I prefer to include it in case Domain Y is accessed by some other page that sets the `window.name` property. Also note that you're not required to use JSON (and that you shouldn't if you're dealing with dinosaur browsers), but I like JSON because I can pass more than one property in an object.

EDIT: If you need Domain Y to pass data back to Domain X, you can have Domain Y save data in `window.name` and navigate to a passer page on Domain X, which can easily pass data to the original window. Try this:

On Domain Y:

```
// Somewhere earlier in the code:
var PREFIX = "your prefix here";
// Call this function when the Done button is clicked.
function passDataBack(data){
    window.name = PREFIX + JSON.stringify(data);
    window.location = "http://www.domain-x.com/passer.html";
}
```

On http://www.domain-x.com/passer.html:

```
// Somewhere earlier in the code:
var PREFIX = "your prefix here";
if(window.name.substr(0, PREFIX.length) == PREFIX){
    // Remove prefix and decode JSON
    var data = JSON.parse(window.name.substring(PREFIX.length));
    // Send data to parent window
    window.opener.processData(data);
}
```

In the original page, there should be a function called `processData` that takes the data and does something with it.

Comment: This is an awesome hack. I've used it without any problems in production.

Answer (score 1):

You need to investigate

[CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) (for older IEs you will need [XDR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) or

[window messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) or

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or

send the variables via the url

Comment: I am reading about it, although a demo code would be really appreciable

Comment: there are demos all over the place. First figure our which technology you want to use. I am sorry I do not have time to paste 4 examples or writes some from scratch since I would need code on two domains/subdomains. If you have full access to the code on both domains, try CORS.

Comment: Ok thanks i will try CORS and check if it can resolve my issue

Comment: CORS is really simple. You just need to return some [headers](http://arunranga.com/examples/access-control/SimpleXSInvocation.txt) on server B to allow server A to access stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I think this may be a more appropriate answer to the question

You should add the following code to the **`http://domain-x.com`**

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  console.log(event.data); // {user: 'data'}
}, false);
```

... at the **`http://domain-y.com`**

```
userClicksDone() {
  try {
    // This may throw an error in case of people access
    // http://domain-y.com directly, not via popup from
    // http://domain-x.com
    //
    window.opener.postMessage({user: 'data'}, 'http://domain-x.com');
  } catch(e) { }

  // Closes this popup
  //
  window.close();
}
```

More info at [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage).
Credits to @mplungjan